# Embedding matplotlib in PyQt4

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqt4

I'm trying to embed matplotlib in a PyQt4+Python 2.7 application so that I can visualize image (i.e. 2D) data in my UI. I'd like to make use of some of matplotlib's functionality such as colormaps, zooming, etc. I've found a few tutorials online but the closest thing that comes to my problem is the following SO question:

[Embedding matplotlib in pyqt4 using imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641901/embedding-matplotlib-in-pyqt4-using-imshow)

Like the author, I'd also like to use "imshow(...)". By following a tutorial online I can embed matplotlib in my UI as a QWidget as follows:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class matPlotLibImage(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.x = np.arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        self.y = np.cos(2*np.pi*self.x)
        self.axes.plot(self.x, self.y)
        super(MatPlotLibImage, self).__init__(self.fig)
```

In my QDockWidget-derived class code I can then embed the above matplotlib widget via:

```
self.mainImage = MatPlotLibImage()
self.setWidget(self.mainImage)
```

This works and displays a simple plot as expected. Now, however, I'd like to display image data represented as numpy arrays. All the examples I'm seeing online are using variants of the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np

img = mpimg.imread("someImage.png")
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
```

My question is: how do I combine the two approaches so that I can use 'imshow()' but embedded as I did for the simple plot? Thank you in advance.

Clarification: Strictly speaking, it's not crucial that I use 'imshow(whatever)', I'm just interested in displaying image data (in a numpy array) in my embedded matplotlib widget. However, imshow does have some useful things that I'd like to leverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you only need to replace the line `self.axes.plot(self.x, self.y)` with

```
self.axes.imshow(img)
```

where `img` is the numpy array of the image, that you will have to have loaded previous to that.

Comment: Thank you. Please see my comment below.